# Which sei? The number or the conjugation of essere?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There are two types of *sei*, the number and the conjugation of *essere*.

How would you figure out which *sei* the person is talking about?

Comment: No matter how hard I try, I'm unable to come up with a sentence where one could be mistaken for the other.

Comment: @Tia27: That's always clear by the context.

Comment: The structures in which the two words appear are totally different. You should not be concerned that these two words have identical form. If there were danger of ambiguity the Italians would have differentiated these words. But there is no danger of confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the only Italian word that has different meanings: we call them *parole omografe*, that is, with the same spelling. There are homographs also in English, like *bow*, but in Italian the situation is different, because same spelling implies “almost identical pronunciation”.

Some of the monosyllabic homographs are distinguished with an accent; in the past it used to be required to mark an accent also on the verbal forms *dài* and *dànno*, a rule which is nowadays not observed any more.

Words like *venti*, *pesca* or *botte* can be distinguished in speech by the fact that the different meanings are conveyed by the quality of the tonic vowel (but not all Italian speakers mark it and several even use the wrong vowel, open instead of closed or vice versa).

The numeral/verbal form *sei* is just one of the *many* homographs; in this case the quality of the vowel is the same, but the context will usually make clear the intended meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Given that *sei* as a verb is singular and *sei* is a number so generally goes with plural nouns, it is next to impossible to mess it up.

> Sei pazzo

*You're crazy*

> Sei pazzi

*Six crazy people*

Simply looking at the words behind it, it'll be easy to tell. Also if the subject is expressed

> Tu sei pazzo

that'll be even easier. If you have an example where you feel confused, post it so we can show you the reasoning behind it.